# Displaying hidden nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that shows the results from my large graph as follows:

[image: graph]

Here is my query to show the graph

```
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP) WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" 
and (gap.name contains "CSRF" )  RETURN p
```

The nodes R11_UP and R12_UP have an incoming edge of type FACT; this query is not displaying that. Here is what the graph looks like if I manually show these incoming edges:

[image]

I want to update my query to show these FACT nodes along with the other graph shown by this query. I am unable to design a query for it. I tried several queries, but none of them worked. I am always stuck with this graph at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is no sequence of relationships from `parent` to `gap` that passes through a `FACT` relationship.

If that is true, then your query is working as expected and should not find any `FACT` relationships.

##### Answer 1

Here is one way to display each path `p` and a list of the "factoids" for the nodes in that path.

```
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP)
WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" AND gap.name contains "CSRF"
UNWIND NODES(p) AS n
RETURN p, REDUCE(
  s = [], t IN COLLECT({n: n, facts: [(n)<-[r:FACT]-(f) | {rel: f, fact: f}]}) |
  CASE WHEN SIZE(t.facts) > 0 THEN s + t ELSE s END) AS factoids
```

A "factoid" is a map with these properties:

- `n` is a node in the path that has an incoming `FACT` relationship (even if that relationship is not on the path)
- `rel` is the `FACT` relationship
- `fact` is the source node of that `FACT` relationship

##### Answer 2

@Graphileon's fine answer is more compact, but its result contains a superfluous empty list for every path node that has no incoming `FACT` relationship.

This version of his answer uses [apoc.coll.removeAll](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.removeAll/) to remove the empty lists:

```
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP)
WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" AND gap.name contains "CSRF"
RETURN p,
       apoc.coll.removeAll(
         [node IN NODES(p) | [fp = (node)<-[:FACT]-(f) | fp ]],
         [[]]) AS factPaths
```

Using`apoc.coll.removeAll` to remove empty lists is for convenience and readability, but not necessary. For example, we could use `REDUCE` instead, as in Answer #1.

Comment: solution 1 displays all the FACT nodes available in the graph

Comment: Answer 2 shows the same graph as @Graphileon answer. i do not see any empty nodes in the graph

Comment: I am referring to the actual query result, not the visualization generated by the Browser from that result. In the Browser, select the Table or Text views in the left to see the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this:

```
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP)
WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" AND gap.name contains "CSRF"
RETURN p,
       [node IN nodes(p) |
           [ factPath = (node)<-[:FACT]-(f) | factPath ]
       ] AS factPaths
```

So you basically loop through the nodes on the path p, and pick up any incoming paths with FACT relationships

In case you want to filter out the empty lists (for nodes that do not have incoming FACT rels) it can be done with an additional WHERE

```
MATCH p=(parent:FEATURE)-[*]->(gap:GAP)
WHERE parent.name = "Update Profile" AND gap.name contains "CSRF"
RETURN p,
     [node IN nodes(p) WHERE EXISTS((node)<-[:FACT]-()) |
           [ factPath = (node)<-[:FACT]-(f) | factPath ]
     ] AS factPaths
```

NOTE: factPaths is returned as a nested array of paths. Depending on what you want to do with it (to the viz) or further processing, you may want to use apoc.coll.flatten() to ..eh .. flatten it

Comment: Nice and compact query, but every `node` that has no incoming `FACT`s will be represented by an empty list in `factPaths`.

Comment: @cybersam the graph does not result with empty nodes

Comment: @cybersam  added a WHERE to avoid empty lists.

Comment: @Graphileon does this affect the query performance or the graph?

Comment: you can check that by profiling the execution. The solution by @cybersam is also valid, but it uses apoc, which may or may not align with your policies.